# Starting Red5 server in eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

Below is the error while trying to start Red5 server in eclipse..

> Error launching executable Cannot run program
>   "D:/RED5/red5-1.0.0/red5-debug.sh" (in directory
>   "D:\RED5\red5-1.0.0"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid
>   Win32 application

How to fix this error?

Comment: looks like you are running Linux/unix version on windows. I see `.sh` file

Comment: Ah okay.. I will another one... Thanks..